# Canvas not sending mails. Doubts regarding outgoing_mail.yml

Tags: email, canvas

I've recently installed Canvas LMS on a cloud server. Everything was ok, except for outgoing mails. I'm really new at this, and I don't know how it works. I would appreciate very much if someone could help me with some doubts...

1- What is correct?
a) address: smtp.gmail.com
b) address: "smtp.gmail.com"

Which data should be quoted in outgoing_mail.yml?

2- I've tried filling the fields with my personal gmail address info, but I receive a warning mail about suspicious activities. That means that Canvas actually tries to connect to my gmail account. That's a good sign! But even when I tell to gmail that I recognize this activity, it won't let me continue...
When I enter the Yahoo's smtp information, nothing happens... not even a warning mail...

3- I wanna know if I have to run "canvas_init restart" everytime I edit that configuration file. And "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"?

I really need your help!! Many thanks in advance!!!